# I'm trying to display images horizontally using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a series of images I would like to display horizontally on my website, using CSS and divs.   I've looked at several posts about how to display images horizontally already and I wasn't able to get any of them to work.

Here's the code from the page I'm referring to:

```
 <head>
 <link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css" media=screen>
 <style>
 div.imageBox {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   }

 div.imageBox p {
 text-align: center;
   }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
 <div id="content">
 <div id="container">

 <div class="imageBox">
 <img src="image" width="800" height ="600">
 </div>

 <div class="imageBox">
 <img src="image" width="600" height ="450">
 </div>

 <div class="imageBox">
 <img src="image" width="800" height ="450">
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

and here's the code for the style sheet:

```
body{
font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serfif; 
font-size: 14px;}

div#menu {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
top: 20px;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
background: transparent;
height: 10px;
position: fixed;
}


div#menu ul {
margin: 0;
display: block;
}

div#menu ul li {
padding-right: 55px;
display: inline;
}

div#content {
padding-top: 40px;
text-align: center;
}

div#container{
float: left;
display: inline;
height: 800px;
width: 0px;
}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #000;
}
```

Is there perhaps an easier way for me to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try to change

```
div#container{
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 height: 800px;
 width: 0px;
}
```

into

```
div#container{
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 height: 800px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add:
div.imageBox {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
   display:inline;
   }

You're using divs which are block elements when you should be using something inline.

Answer (score 1):

Images will align next to each other. If you need the divs, you can give them the style `display: inline` to make them behave in the same way. You can also use `float: left`, but that will make things harder in most cases.

You can apply styles like margins and borders to images too, so you may not need the divs. Although I'm not sure how you want it to look exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/d5sYM/

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {width: 100px; height: 100px;}
        .imageBox {display: inline-block; border: 1px solid grey; background: silver; padding: 4px; text-align: center; font-size: 10px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="http://screenshots.en.softonic.com/en/scrn/80000/80669/easter-icons-5.jpg"><br>
        Image 1
    </div>
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="http://l-userpic.livejournal.com/82523298/2181918"><br>
        Image 2
    </div>
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="http://www.jellymuffin.com/icons/emo/images/30.jpg"><br>
        Image 3
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```